# Calling class of a for all .selected elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build a filtering tool that filters by 2 criteria at once. I have:

```
<ul class="filters">
    <li class="colors"><a class="blue" href="#filter"></a></li>
    <li class="colors"><a class="red" href="#filter"></a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="filters">
    <li class="shapes"><a class="square" href="#filter"></a></li>
    <li class="shapes"><a class="circle" href="#filter"></a></li>
</ul>

<div class="dojofilter blue square"></div>
<div class="dojofilter blue circle"></div>
<div class="dojofilter red square"></div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('.filters li').click(function () {
    var liClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.' + liClass).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});

$('.filters li').click(function () {
    var SelClass = $('.selected').children('a').attr('class');
    var Others = $('div.dojofilter').not('.' + SelClass);
    $('div.' + SelClass).animate({
        height: '480px',
        width: '310px',
        opacity: '1',
    });
    $(Others).animate({
        height: '0px',
        width: '0px',
        opacity: '0'
    });
```

So with that first function I am assigning an additional class "selected" to the links, but only 1 shape and 1 color can be "selected" at any given time. That is working well.

Trouble is that I can't get it show only the red square, for example. Also you can toggle shapes, but once you toggle a single color, the shapes stop working.

Well, just look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j6fXr/

I don't really know Firebug, but it seems to show that when you click one of the links, the "this" is only focusing on that link's class - so either shape or color - rather than all .selected links. Not sure why that would be...

What I am missing?

**EDIT** - The shapes animation only works if you click them before clicking the colors. So once the fiddle breaks, click "Run" to reset it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('.filters li').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');

    var color = $('.filters li.colors.selected').data('filter');
    var shape = $('.filters li.shapes.selected').data('filter');

    var $divs = $('.dojofilter'), $filtered = $divs;
    if(color){
        $filtered = $filtered.filter('.' + color)
    }
    if(shape){
        $filtered = $filtered.filter('.' + shape)
    }
    $filtered.show();
    $divs.not($filtered).hide()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AByx6/)

Comment: Awesome.  I stuck with my own version of applying the selected class, because in the actual application I am dealing with multiple ul's (so not all the li's are siblings), but otherwise this was exactly what I needed. Clean and concise. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I reorganized a little bit your code, but I think this is what you are looking for.

Using `toggleClass` you can add/remove the `selected` class to your elements.

Then you have to parse every selected elements to get their classes and construct a css selector for multiple classes.

Here's the updated jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/j6fXr/1/

Comment: This is good except that you can select both colors or both shapes at once. Easy to fix though. Thanks.